# Using sed or awk to delete slash from fields

Tags: bash, scripting, sed, awk

I'm trying to remove any slashes between any | between \ \ which include a name'

```
10.46|5060|100002366551140|\WAPNER| M\ |100002366551750
```

Desired output

```
10.46|5060|100002366551140|WAPNER M |100002366551750
```

while using sed or awk , your help is highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat file
10.46|5060|100002366551140|\WAPNER| M\ |100002366551750

$ sed 's/\\\([^\\]*\)|\([^\\]*\)\\/\1\2/' file
10.46|5060|100002366551140|WAPNER M |100002366551750
```

If you don't want to remove the "\"s, just move them inside the parentheses.

Comment: nice and clean! you are smart!

Comment: Do you know how can I manage to resolve the same issue, if I get more slashes in the name ex |\WAPNER| John |M\| get the output to be |WAPNER John  M |  
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Alternative awk you could try in case of multiple back slashes:

```
awk -F\| '!(NR%2){$1=$1}1' RS=\\ ORS= OFS= file
```

or:

```
awk -F\\ '{for(i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub(/\|/,x,$i)}1' OFS= file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to handle cases like this:

```
10.46|5060|100002366551140|\WAPNER| M\ |100002366551750
10.12|\FOO| BAR| BAZ\|12|\X| Y| Z\|14
```

I don’t think you can do it easily with sed, because of the need to
iteratively apply replacements on parts of matched regular expressions.

It’s pretty straightforward to do in Python. `doit.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import re
import sys

RE = re.compile(r'\\([^\\]*\|[^\\]*)\\')

for line in sys.stdin.readlines():
    matchiter = RE.finditer(line)
    while 1:
        for match in matchiter:
            matching_text = match.group(0)
            replacement_text = match.group(1).replace('|', '')
            line = line.replace(matching_text, replacement_text)
        else:
            break
    print line,
```

In pseudocode:

- While there are any `|` symbols between `\`s:

  - Grab the part between `\`’s (accessed as  `match.group(1)` in Python), and strip out the
    `|`s inside then. Save it as `replacement_text`
  - Then replace the original text that matched, including `\`’s, with
    `replacement_text`, and loop

It works!

```
$ cat input
10.46|5060|100002366551140|\WAPNER| M\ |100002366551750
10.12|\FOO| BAR| BAZ\|12|\X| Y| Z\|14
$ ./doit.py < input
10.46|5060|100002366551140|WAPNER M |100002366551750
10.12|FOO BAR BAZ|12|X Y Z|14
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

`sed -re 's/\\(\w+)(\|)([ A-Za-z]+)\\/\1 \3/g' temp.txt`

output

`10.46|5060|100002366551140|WAPNER  M |100002366551750`