# how to delete | between multiple back backslash(s)

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk

I have got similar question answerd on here before, but this time, it is a little more challenging for me, all what I need is to remove | between name "\WAPNER| john | M\"

it will be a plus to remove the back slashes too.

file

```
10.46|5060|100002366551140|\WAPNER| john | M\ |100002366551750
```

Desired output

```
 10.46|5060|100002366551140|\WAPNER john  M\ |100002366551750
```

it will be perfect if your solution will also work with names with single slash :)

```
 10.46|5060|100002366551140|\WAPNER|  M\ |100002366551750
```

output will be

```
 10.46|5060|100002366551140|\WAPNER M\ |100002366551750
```

Thank you

Comment: You already asked this [earlier today](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484220/using-sed-or-awk-to-delete-slash-from-fields/14484726#14484726). Were the answers there helpful? If not, you can comment and edit your question, instead of creating a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU Sed):

```
sed -r '/\\[^\\]*\\/{s//\n&\n/;h;s/[\\|]//g;G;s/.*\n(.*)\n.*\n(.*)\n.*\n/\2\1/}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
awk -F '\\'  '{ gsub("|", "", $2); print $0 }'  inputfile > newfile
```

Comment: will this work with names which has 2 slashes as well? example \WAPNER | M\

Comment: Yes, the slashes are removed because IFS is set  to \ which is the '\\' escaped backslash.  OFS remains the default, so when the $0 string is written all \ chars ignored when printing.  If there are some  \'s you have to keep this code will not work for you.

Comment: +1 for the solution but ITYM FS not IFS in your comment. For @user1007727 - don't keep changing your requirements, just tell us what it really is you need to do so we can help you solve it one time.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo "10.46|5060|100002366551140|\WAPNER| john | M\ |100002366551750" | awk -F'|' '{print $1"|"$2"|"$3"|"$4$5$6"|"$7}' | sed s.\\\\..g
10.46|5060|100002366551140|WAPNER john  M |100002366551750
```

Note it'll work only assuming there are always 3 '|' chars to remove.

UPDATE: seems I didn't notice the title - if you want to remove all '|' characters between a pair of '\'s, jim mcnamara's solution is better.

Answer (score 0):

try this

`sed -re 's/\\(\w+)(\|)( \w* )(\|)([ A-Za-z]+)\\/\1\3\5/g' temp.txt`

output

`10.46|5060|100002366551140|WAPNER  john   M |100002366551750`